# "more leads mean more sales" or "more leads means more sales"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, conjugation

I was just wondering which one is grammatically correct.

> "more leads **mean** more sales"

OR

> "more leads **means** more sales"

Of course, "more leads" is plural, but the sentence implies "Getting more leads means more sales".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are right: *the sentence implies "Getting more leads means more sales"*.

Both are grammatically correct.

They just mean slightly different things. With *means* (reference to singular object), all those 'more leads' together constitute the factor for 'more sales'; with *mean* (reference to plural object), each of the leads is implied to contribute to more sales.

Per usage, we only say *More leads **means** more sales*, though. That's only understandable I suppose.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you correct the first sentence of your message? (Your are right)? I cannot edit and it is driving me nuts...

Comment: With the ellipsis revealed, *getting more leads* is a singular object. Hope it's clearer now.